# Adaptive quadrature methods for Fourier Optics

Tags: quadrature, fourier-analysis

In Fourier Optics one often needs to compute approximations to bivariate integrals like
$$
\int_{-\frac{l}{2}}^{\frac{l}{2}}\int_{-\frac{l}{2}}^{\frac{l}{2}} {\rm e}^{i\phi(\xi,\eta)}\mathrm{exp}\left[i\frac{\pi}{\lambda d}\left((x-\xi)^2-(y-\eta)^2\right)\right]{\rm d}\xi{\rm d}\eta
$$
These integrals generally reduce to a form that, after discretization, can be solved by a 2-D DFT (see [1, Chap. 5]). There are some technical issues however that have to be taken care of, like aliasing, etc. I was wondering if there are any adaptive quadrature algorithms that would work more like a "black box"?

[1] Goodman, J. W. (2017). [Introduction to Fourier Optics](https://www.worldcat.org/title/introduction-to-fourier-optics/oclc/958780856).

Comment: I have no idea if this is a good advice, so I am not going to put it as an answer. MATLAB and Octave have a function called integral2 (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html), which is what you want. But I don't know optics, maybe you deal with high frequency waves. In which case, numerical quadrature rules may give you wrong answers.

Comment: Is there any reason for you not converting your problem to a DFT and use FFT?

Comment: Conversion to a DFT is indeed the standard way to compute approximations to these integrals. As Goodman points out, however, one has to be careful with issues like aliasing as I pointed out in the original question. See Chap. 5 of his book for more details.

Comment: If you use @ before the username, the person will be notified. I was asking with the aim of improving your question so you get answers. Most people won't go check complete references, though.